# How do you print a single copy of a string in a -while- loop?

Tags: python

Just starting python and finally got to -while- loops

*went to if-else's, functions, and for/while loops only

How do you get this to print only itself?

```
def hangman(secret):
    tries = 5
    word = ''
    while tries > 0:
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter: ")
        for index in secret:
            common = 0
            for char in guess:
                if char in index:
                    common = 1 """checks whether they have something in 
                                  commmon"""
            if common == 1 or index in " .?!": """checks if the secret_word 
                                                 has the 4 characters"""
                word = word + index """word is now the common letters"""
            else:
                word = word + '-' """letters not in common are a dash"""
        tries -= 1
        print 'You have', tries, 'tries left.'
        print word


>>> hangman('hello')
Guess a letter: h
You have 4 tries left.
h----
Guess a letter: e
You have 3 tries left.
h-----e---
Guess a letter: l
You have 2 tries left.
h-----e-----ll-
Guess a letter: o
You have 1 tries left.
h-----e-----ll-----o
Guess a letter: a
You have 0 tries left.
h-----e-----ll-----o-----
```

p.s I'm not sure if I even did the code correctly all I know is that it runs.
    return ends the loop

Comment: There is no way at all to understand how you expect this code to work from your question.

Comment: hmm.. `print "itself"`?

Comment: All of the extra `-` come from your `for` loop, not the `while` loop.

Comment: `"""` does not create a multi-line comment, but rather a mult-line *string*. When you write `'-' """letters not in common are a dash"""` then Python will concatenate the two strings together to make `'-letters not in common are a dash'`.  There is one and only one way to make a comment in Python, and that is with the `#` character. You should only use bare strings as docstrings, which are strings not assigned to a variable that are created at the top of a function before any other code is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else condition which includes the'-'